# How to distort an image to create flag waving in the wind effect using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, canvas

Given an image, I need to create an animation of the image being distorted as though it's a flag waving in the wind, using javascript and an html5 canvas.

Bonus: I also would like to be able to export this animation as a png.

Comment: You do realize that only two browsers actually support animated PNGs?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've created a [simple example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_flag_wave.html) of a flag waving in the wind. It's ugly because I draw the flag to fill the canvas (instead of leaving padding for the flag to wave into) and because I don't make any attempt at anti-aliasing. <strike>I also didn't make any attempt to provide 3D shading, which would help the effect.</strike>

I can get 64fps with a 320px wide flag in Chrome v8 on my machine. If you want to test the speed yourself, change the fps on line 59 to `1000` and uncomment lines 63 and 82; it will then output fps information every 100 frames to the console.

This won't work in IE8-, even with [ExCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/), because there is no mechanism to access individual pixel data there.

**Edit**: Just for fun, I've updated the sample to shade the ripples as they go through the image.

**Edit2**: For more fun, I added padding to the flag drawing (no more clipping) and I added a 'squeeze' factor that lets you make the right side of the flag bigger or smaller than the original (for perspective). Since it slows down the performance a little I've uploaded it as [a separate sample](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_flag_wave2.html).

[image: US Flag waving in the wind (static screenshot)]

Comment: Finally, here's [one final sample](http://phrogz.net/tmp/gkheadwave.html) showing how to use this with an image you load yourself (from the same domain) instead of a drawn flag.

Comment: +1 for the demo. :) I take back my answer then. (Your first "simple example" doesn't work for some reason, the other two are fine though.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I knew a great mind would tackle this problem! Now if only there was a simple way to save this animation, base64 encoded image or something along those lines might do the trick... =)

Comment: @Andres You can save an HTML canvas as a [base64 encoded PNG](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl), but that would be one data url per frame, not as an animation.

Comment: @Phrogz That's a pity. I basically just need to be able to reuse this canvas animation over a cartesian map on repeated occasions based on several x,y coordinates. So I figured if I could process it once, save it and then reuse it, it would save me a lot of hassle. I think I saw somewhere a way to reuse a canvas on another canvas. Maybe that's the answer. My goal with base64 was really to see if I could send this base64 back to the server for storing this flag animation for later use.

Comment: Well, you could easily use the data URLs as a series of PNGs loaded (locally), one replacing the next using `setInterval`, to recreate the animation. As Eli noted, support for MNG is (sadly) very sparse, so even if you had created one it probably would not have helped you.

Comment: @Phrogz I'll do that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Phrogz, nice work, i am so exited that you made this waving flag, can you help me and modified it a little more, this is my example. http://www.americkiplakari.org/zastavanovo.html I want to image be fixed at the top and moving from top to bottom, Txanks mate you are the greatest