# Waving flag in html

Tags: html, css, animation, html5-canvas

In my job I've got task to make animate of waving flag on site. I think about canvas, but my employers would rather use only CSS3 and animate, 3d transform, keyframe.

I think to make this kind of animation I need to have 3D mesh or have a lot of htmls tag what, I think looking disgusting in code and animation would look horrible.

I read about Shader, but it is supported only by Chrome.

Does someone have other ideas?

Comment: follow this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362248/how-to-distort-an-image-to-create-flag-waving-in-the-wind-effect-using-html5-can   a good answer by `Phrogz`

Comment: I've read @Phrogz answer, it is great, but it is based on canvas and need a lot of plugins. So I think for one animation, making site loading so slower is unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity, I would suggest a simple animated GIF. The right tools should be selected for the job, not the tools selected beforehand (your employers need to be told this).