# Waving flag effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

Actually I don't know where to start. I tried somethings with images overlapped but that was bad idea, because of needed many images preloaded.

Question: Is there any handy method to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a .gif file?

Comment: I just to try to accomplish this with javascript if it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362248/how-to-distort-an-image-to-create-flag-waving-in-the-wind-effect-using-html5-can

Comment: Why my question -1? No expert here that has a proper answer?

Comment: @user2032890, yeah this is possible, but again with anim gifs =)

Comment: See the ["how to ask" section of the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask); you haven't shared any research in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sprite image (many images in one, to reduce loading time), and a div container, then change the background position of the image to animate the whole thing.