# How can I simulate the movement of cloth in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, simulation

I am looking to simulate a subtle movement (think wave) of cloth in browser entirely with an image effectively placed on top and then have the background do the processing of the movement? Is this possible?
Effectively imagine it as a cloth simulation with an image (as this will need to change dependant on the product) stuck on top of it.

Hope this helps.

Also would be good to know if this could work on a mobile phone too.

Comment: Something like this? http://jlongster.com/s/lljs-cloth/

Comment: @CzechErface indeed, however I would love to know how to apply an image to it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could process the image on a per pixel basis, apply time dependent transformations on it, and draw it on a canvas element.

It will involve some interesting maths, and one of the primary concerns would be performance, but i think a fairly optimal implementation should work easily on modern Desktops.
Whether it works on mobile devices depends on their HTML5 support and processing power.

you might want to start with simple things such as this question

[Add flaglike waving to 2d Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668914/add-flaglike-waving-to-2d-context)

related links -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas