# Image gets dimmer after animation in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

**Question**

> I want to restore the *original brightness* of the image after animation. What should I do?

**Description**

In the following code, I have drawn the image in the form of *strips*. Each strip is displaced along the vertical axis by some amount (similar to water waves simulation, got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668914/add-flaglike-waving-to-2d-context?lq=1)). But, after the animation, the image got *dimmer* by some amount. Why it is so?

**Code**

```js
window.onload = () => {
    // Setup
    const cvs = document.getElementById("cvs");
    cvs.width = window.innerWidth;
    cvs.height = window.innerHeight;
    const c = cvs.getContext("2d");
    c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
    
    let phase = 0, margin = 30;
    
    // Flag Image
    let flag = new Image();
    flag.src = document.getElementById("India").src;
    
    flag.onload = () => {
        // c.drawImage(flag, margin, margin); 
        
        // Uncomment the above line and comment out the below line, if you want to see the original contrast.
        
        setInterval(wave, 120);
    }
    
    // Animate function
    let wave = () => {
        c.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
        
        let wid = flag.width;
        
        // Drawing flag in the form of slits
        for(let i = 0; i < wid; i++) {
            let y = margin + Math.sin(i/30 + phase) * 4;
            c.drawImage(flag, i, 0, 1, flag.height, margin + i, y , 0.5, flag.height);
        }
        
        phase += 0.5;
    }
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#India {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/icpsgo3o2hnw64h/510px-Flag_of_India.svg.jpg?raw=1" id="India"/>
        <canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Image before animation

[image]

Image while animation

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not certain but could potentially be due to aliasing when drawing the pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 0.5 to 1 in this line:

```
c.drawImage(flag, i, 0, 1, flag.height, margin + i, y , 0.5, flag.height);
```